# More direct way of duplicating Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've been searching for how to duplicate a solution.  In my case, I just want to move my solution to a new directory (it got created in the Visual Studio directory under "Projects" and I want it to be in the folder for the course I'm taking).

I understand there is the problem of absolute paths.  But the only things that should have absolute paths are resources like pictures I'm using or stuff like that.  I'd be happy to do those by hand.

To help me understand why it is so complicated, maybe someone can explain why there isn't simply a "save as" sort of option.

Here are two places I've looked at so far:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/a0847416-392c-4ce3-8e9c-40cb7f0f2a27/visual-studio-c-how-to-copy-a-project

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/866577-how-copy-entire-visual-c-solution

Why can't save-as at least just update the automatically generated paths?

Comment: So you copy the directory over and open up the csproj or sln and what happens?

Comment: You should be able to just copy/paste everything, this is essentially what TFS does.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy paste the entire solution directory to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't save-as at least just update the automatically generated paths?

Because your solution can have items included from the "outside" (outside the solution root dir).

BTW, don't forget to manually change project guids if some projects from your solution_s_ can eventually end up in one (common) solution.